# How to use U-Boot to load application onto board

Tags: c, linux, gcc, cross-compiling, toolchain

I've installed, compiled and built U-Boot on my host machine in order to load an application (a hello world program in C) onto my board. The board is a FOX G20 V with an ATMEL AT91SAM9G20 processor. The U-Boot compiles fine, and I've compiled my application with `arm-none-eabi-gcc` which is an ARM embedded gcc toolchain by Linaro (http://www.linaro.org/) to cross compile my application onto my board. But now I'm awfully confused.

I've configured U-Boot to run on my board with the `make` options. But now, my question is, once U-Boot is compiled and built on my host machine, do I need to install it on my board as well? If so, how do I do that? If not, how do I load my application (the executable file) onto my board once U-Boot is built?

I have read the tutorials online but it still confuses me even more when I read them so I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely have to install u-boot on your board. It looks like your board boots from a micro SD card so that will be easy.

For now let's say we don't care about the SD card partitioning. All you have to do is copy the u-boot image at the beginning of the SD card with dd :

```
dd if=u-boot.bin of=/dev/<xxx>
```

where /dev/ is the sdcard device on your PC, generaly /dev/sdb or /dev/mmc0

This will overwrite the partition table of the SD card so **all data on this sd card will be lost**. It is possible to preserve the partition table and content with other options too.

Then put you SD card on the board and boot from it. You should see u-boot logs on the uart console.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Once I load the u-boot.bin file on my SD card and put it back into my board, what do you mean by "boot from it"? Is this to load my application onto the board? And how exactly do I boot from the SD card on the board? Sorry about all the questions but I'm kind of still confused.

Comment: Also, I'm still unsure of how to install U-Boot on my board.

Comment: I've manually copied the `u-boot.bin`, `u-boot.map`, `uboot.srec` and `System.map` files onto my SD card. What is the next step?

Comment: Your processor expects to find the bootloader binary on the first sector of the SD card *.

Comment: That should be done. But now, how do I boot from the board's SD card to load and execute my application?

Comment: ...Continuing previous comment, I submitted too fast.

You have to make a raw binary copy of the bootloader uboot.bin to you SDcard using dd. Copying u-boot.bin to the filesystem on the sd card is not enough because your processor doesn't know how to handle a formatted partition.

Most processors can also skip the partition table when they look for the bootloader on an SDcard. 
For your first boot it is simpler to just write the bootloader image on the first sector and overwrite the partition table.

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase: I copied the binary file onto the board, then used dd to copy it onto the SD card. And I'm sorry but I don't understand your last sentence. All in all, now that there is a raw binary copy of uboot.bin in the SD card, how do I just simply load my program and execute it?

Comment: Well that depends, does your program need Linux to run ?

Comment: It shouldn't since I cross compiled my code using an ARM embedded toochain `arm-none-eabi-gcc` and configured the boot so that it would be compatible with my board.

Comment: Then you have to copy your program to the SD card at a given address (you can choose what you want). In u-boot you have to copy it from the SD card to the RAM at ${loadaddr} and then run **'bootm'** to execute it. Look at the help for 'mmc read' command in u-boot for that. You may need to convert your program binary to a u-boot image with **mkimage** from package u-boot-tools too. People generally load a linux kernel from u-boot but you could load whatever binary you want.